# Dirt cheap USB torch - with ONLY on & off

Tags: torch

I have some lovely (and cheap) USB torches, from AliExpres, Temu, etc, which are USB chargeable.

The problem is that, even when dirt cheap, they are also full featured.

I want to click a button, have light; click it again, have dark. All of mine force me to cycle through 6 or 8 types of lightning just to turn off.

Cheap & cheerful on  off - any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to do this manually or automatically ?

Comment: manually, please

Answer (score 1):

I found this on a NZ website.  While it has multi-functions, flicking teh dual-position switch the other way gives you your favourite setting.

[Klarus XT21X Pro 4400 Lumen Tactical Flashlight](https://www.rubbermonkey.co.nz/Klarus-XT21X-Pro-4400-Lumen-Tactical-Flashlight)

> .....XT21X Pro features a side switch and a tailcap dual-switch with a memory function to keep your preferred setting just a click away......

[image]

Comment: Yikes!! 190 bucks!!  I upvoted you, though, as it does what I ask. Please forgive me for not awarding you the answer, coz... dirt cheap??